# How can I get the total amount of time overlap between Dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Say I have two pandas dataframes:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Start": {
            0: "2019-07-19 07:00:00",
            1: "2019-07-19 08:00:00",
            2: "2019-07-19 10:00:00",
        },
        "Finish": {
            0: "2019-07-19 07:30:00",
            1: "2019-07-19 08:30:00",
            2: "2019-07-19 10:30:00",
        },
    }
)

df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Start": {0: "2019-07-19 07:30:00", 1: "2019-07-19 08:15:00",},
        "Finish": {0: "2019-07-19 08:00:00", 1: "2019-07-19 09:00:00",},
    }
)
df1.Start = pd.to_datetime(df1.Start)
df2.Finish = pd.to_datetime(df2.Finish)
```

They look like this:

```
|    | Start               | Finish              |
|---:|:--------------------|:--------------------|
|  0 | 2019-07-19 07:00:00 | 2019-07-19 07:30:00 |
|  1 | 2019-07-19 08:00:00 | 2019-07-19 08:30:00 |
|  2 | 2019-07-19 10:00:00 | 2019-07-19 10:30:00 |

|    | Start               | Finish              |
|---:|:--------------------|:--------------------|
|  0 | 2019-07-19 07:30:00 | 2019-07-19 08:00:00 |
|  1 | 2019-07-19 08:15:00 | 2019-07-19 09:00:00 |
```

Here's what it looks if I plot them (colouring in the part between `Start` and `Finish` of each row):
[image]

Think of it as if `df1` records times when `TV1` was on, and `df2` records times when `TV2` was on. I would like to find the total amount of time that *any* TV was on. In the plot above, this is shown with the line `df1 or df2`.

### ADDENDUM

Here's how I made the plot:

```
import plotly.figure_factory as ff

df3 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Start": {0: "2019-07-19 07:00:00", 1: "2019-07-19 10:00:00",},
        "Finish": {0: "2019-07-19 09:00:00", 1: "2019-07-19 10:30:00",},
    }
)
df1['Resource'] = ['df1']*3
df2['Resource'] = ['df2']*2
df3['Resource'] = ['df1 or df2']*2
df1['Task'] = ['df1']*3
df2['Task'] = ['df2']*2
df3['Task'] = ['df1 or df2']*2

fig = ff.create_gantt(
    pd.concat([df1, df2, df3]).reset_index(drop=True),
    group_tasks=True,
    index_col="Resource",
)
fig.show()
```

and here's out I printed out the Dataframes:

```
from tabulate import tabulate

print(df1.pipe(tabulate, headers="keys", tablefmt="pipe"))
print(df2.pipe(tabulate, headers="keys", tablefmt="pipe"))
```

Comment: Where is the `event` column? or does each row represent an event? Also, does the minutes different matter or you just need the hour difference?

Comment: Each row represents an event. I'll be expressing the difference in seconds, so the whole timestamp matters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note, the input here is based on the original question.

---

I'm not sure if this can be done nicely since you are always comparing rows, but one way:

```
df1['start_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['start_time'])
df2['start_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['start_time'])
df1['end_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['end_time'])
df2['end_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['end_time'])

all_events = pd.concat((df1, df2)).sort_values('start_time')
result = all_events.iloc[0:1].copy()
for _, row in all_events.iterrows():
    if row['start_time'] <= result['end_time'].iloc[-1]:
        if row['end_time'] > result['end_time'].iloc[-1]:
            result['end_time'].iloc[-1] = row['end_time']
    else:
        result = result.append(row, ignore_index=True)

print(all_events)
print(result)
```

The starting part is just to let Pandas handle my time comparison by itself. The basics:

1. Create a table of all events
2. sort them by start time
3. Add the first row to your result
4. For each new line, is the start time is prior to the last added end time?

   - Yes: if the new end time is greater than the previous one, update it.
   - No: add this row as a new line to the result, since it does not intersect.

Results for your table (sorted all events and the result):

```
             end_time          start_time
0 2019-07-19 06:07:10 2019-07-19 06:04:57
1 2019-07-19 06:27:41 2019-07-19 06:26:33
2 2019-07-19 06:35:43 2019-07-19 06:33:18
0 2019-07-19 06:35:53 2019-07-19 06:34:56
1 2019-07-19 06:37:45 2019-07-19 06:36:44
2 2019-07-19 06:40:11 2019-07-19 06:38:33
3 2019-07-19 06:40:25 2019-07-19 06:38:37
4 2019-07-19 07:02:20 2019-07-19 06:59:48
3 2019-07-19 07:06:47 2019-07-19 07:01:20
4 2019-07-19 07:09:19 2019-07-19 07:07:17
             end_time          start_time
0 2019-07-19 06:07:10 2019-07-19 06:04:57
1 2019-07-19 06:27:41 2019-07-19 06:26:33
2 2019-07-19 06:35:53 2019-07-19 06:33:18
3 2019-07-19 06:37:45 2019-07-19 06:36:44
4 2019-07-19 06:40:25 2019-07-19 06:38:33
5 2019-07-19 07:06:47 2019-07-19 06:59:48
6 2019-07-19 07:09:19 2019-07-19 07:07:17
```

The actual deltas are just:

```
>>> print(result['end_time'] - result['start_time'])
0   00:02:13
1   00:01:08
2   00:02:35
3   00:01:01
4   00:01:52
5   00:06:59
6   00:02:02
```

Comment: Thanks! Sorry for the changing the input, that was just so that I could make a nice plot with `plotly`

Comment: Thanks for this great answer and explanation - it's in moments like that I feel embarassed that upvotes on questions are worth as much on those on answers

Comment: @ign you're quite welcome.  Don't be embarrassed, you'd be surprised how difficult good questions are to come by.